# Getting ": command not found" (: is a colon) error starting a terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Seemingly out of nowhere, when I open a terminal session, I get a series of errors like:

```
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: invalid shell option name
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: invalid shell option name
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
bash: /home/user/.bashrc: line 35: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''
'ash: /home/user/.bashrc: line 35: `case "$TERM" in
```

I did recently add something to `~.bashrc`, but I was just changing the `PATH`. Looking at `.bashrc`, it looks perfectly fine.

What could account for this? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

I had accidentally changed the line endings in `.bashrc` to CRLF (DOS/Windows) rather than just LF (*nix).

To fix it, I changed them back. For instance, with `vi` or `vim`:

1. Open the file.
2. To verify the problem, type a colon (`:`) to go to command mode, then type
   `set fileformat?`
   and press Enter. That will probably show you `fileformat=dos` on the bottom line of the editor, confirming you've accidentally changed your `.bashrc` line endings.
3. To fix it, type a colon (`:`), then type
   `set fileformat=unix`
   and press Enter.
4. To save and exit, type a colon, then `wq` and Enter.

Comment: I signed in and joined community, just to say THANK YOU SO MUCH. had downloaded and installed stuff on Windows and when I tried to access it using WSL nothing was working. You're a lifesaver 